# What is the difference between "window.location.href" and "window.location.hash"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, href, window.location

I learned **"window.location.hash"** new and tried in my jquery code instead of **"window.location.href"** and both of them gave same results.

Code is here :

```
window.location.href = ($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"));
window.location.hash = ($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"));
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: The value of this property could be different in different browsers. A safe way to get the hash property would be to instead use: `var hash = (location.href.split("#")[1] || "");`

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/get-your-hash-the-bulletproof-way/
`var hash = location.hash.substring(1);`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For a URL like `http://[www.example.com]:80/search?q=devmo#test`

- `hash` - returns the part of the URL that follows the `#` symbol, including the `#` symbol. You can listen for the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) *event* to get notified of changes to the hash in supporting browsers.

  ```
  Returns: #test
  ```
- `href` - returns the entire URL.

  ```
  Returns: http://[www.example.com]:80/search?q=devmo#test
  ```

---

### [Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 11):

Test it on for example `http://stackoverflow.com/#Page`

```
href = http://stackoverflow.com/#Page
```

```
hash = #Page
```

Answer (score 4):

href is the url

hash is only the anchor after the url

http://www.xxxxxxx.com#anchor

http://www.xxxxxxx.com#anchor is the href

"#anchor" is the hash

Answer (score 3):

`hash` and `href` are both properties of the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object. `hash` is the part of the URL from the `#` on (or an empty string if there is no `#`), while `href` is a string representation of the whole URL.

Comment: Pretty sure it includes the `#` character.

Answer (score 3):

The hash property returns the anchor portion of a URL, including the hash sign (#).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple example for difference between `window.location.href` and `window.location.hash`

For the URL `http://www.manm.com/member/#!create`:

- href: `http://www.manam.com/member/#!create`
- hash: `#!create`