# How to understand hash in window.location.hash

Tags: javascript

In w3schools.com, for `window.location.hash` explain is: the hash property sets or returns the anchor part of a URL, including the hash sign (#).

For example: `http://www.example.com/test.htm#part2` return `#part2`

And  "href" abbreviation of hypertext references .

I think hashing is generating a value or values from a string of text using a mathematical function.

This makes me very confused. What does **hash** mean in `window.location.hash`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688401/what-is-the-difference-between-window-location-href-and-window-location-hash maybe reading this answer would give you a hint

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar Thanks a lot. I think a lot about it. I think it's an abbreviated phrase that means something else like `href`.

Answer (score 3):

It's referring to the name of the `#` (ie. "hash") symbol:

> The symbol # is most commonly known as the number sign, hash, or pound sign.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

As for why that symbols is called that, the Oxford English Dictionary thinks it's a corruption of "hatch":

> Origin
>   1960s probably from hatch, altered by association with hash.
>   - https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hash

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very useful. I know # is number sign, but I don't know it can also be expressed as hash or pound sign. Language barrier, study hard.